# Computing a new column based on other columns

Tags: python

I am trying to create a subset of an existing variable (col1) in the below df. My new variable (col2) would only have "a" corresponding to "a" in col1. Rest of the values should be marked as "Others". Please help.

col1
a
b
c
a
b
c
a

Col2
a
Other
Other
a
Other
Other
a

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'a', 'a', 'Other')
#alternative
#df['col2'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'] == 'a', 'Other')
print (df)
  col1   col2
0    a      a
1    b  Other
2    c  Other
3    a      a
4    b  Other
5    c  Other
6    a      a
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**: `np.where`

This is the most direct method:

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'a', 'a', 'Other')
```

**Method 2**: `pd.DataFrame.loc`

```
df['col2'] = 'Other'
df.loc[df['col1'] == 'a', 'col2'] = 'a'
```

**Method 3**: `pd.Series.map`

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map({'a': 'a'}).fillna('Other')
```

Most of these methods can be optimized by extracting `numpy` array representation via `df['col1'].values`.

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional library since the question is not tagged with either pandas nor numpy :

You can use a list comprehension with if and else :

```
col1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
col2 = [ x if x=='a' else 'others' for x in col1 ]
```